# Seperating each day in a month from a pandas dataframe into an excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
Date        Price   Quantity
12/9/2019   21.47   12
12/9/2019   10.65   12
12/9/2019   11.53   18
12/8/2019   6.19    11
12/8/2019   6.04    3
12/8/2019   6.19    2
12/7/2019   6.04    1
12/7/2019   6.04    7
12/7/2019   6.04    1
12/6/2019   6.19    1
12/6/2019   6.19    1
12/6/2019   6.19    2
```

What is the best option if I want to create an excel file for each day? So one would only have the  9th, another the 8th, and so on.

I have tried a for loop but I dont understand how to seperate the date.

Answer (score 0):

Using .groupby and list comps:

```
import pandas as pd


def make_ordinal(val: int) -> str:
    suffix = "th" if 11 <= (int(val) % 100) <= 13 else ["th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th"][min(int(val) % 10, 4)]

    return f"{str(val)}{suffix}"


def create_files(frame: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    dfs = [x.reset_index(drop=True) for _, x in frame.groupby("Date")]

    [x.to_excel(f"path/to/file/{make_ordinal(pd.to_datetime(x['Date']).dt.day[0])}.xlsx", index=False) for x in dfs]
```

Call with:

```
create_files(df)
```